# PHP isset not working with checkbox

Tags: php, checkbox, isset

I have a form where people need to submit information. This part of code is not working how I want it and I don't know why..

```
if (!isset($_POST['maandag']) && !isset($_POST['dinsdag']) && !isset($_POST['geenvoork']))
{
    echo "Je bent vergeten in te vullen wanneer je aanwezig bent.";
}
```

the posts do work in the rest of the form, and are correct. What I want is to check if those 3 checkboxes are not checked. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why dont you use a radiogroup for this?

Comment: You should be checking to see if they are empty, not set. They should always be set, but if they are unchecked, they will be empty.

Comment: @Prisoner No, if a checkbox is not checked, it is not in the `$_POST` array at all.

Comment: @Prisoner: nope, checkbox doesn't send anything if it's not checked

Comment: It's 3 options, you can select one, two, or all three.. it's about wether you'll be there on monday or tuesday, both, or that you don't care when ;)

Comment: Ah, my mistake. I was going to add "if my memory serves me correctly".

Comment: It would be easier to help if we wouldn't have to deal with non-English words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they are in your form then they will be set. You likely want to check if they are false. Here's what it is for one, you can combine the others:

```
if( !isset($_POST['maandag']) || !$_POST['maandag'] ) { 
     // do something
}
```

Secondly the code as is means that you'll only get the message if *none* of the checkboxes are set. I'm not certain, but if you're trying to throw an error message don't you want it if any of them are not set? In which case you need `||` (or) not `&&` (and).

Comment: It should be able to check if all 3 checkboxes aren't checked. If they aren't checked, show the message. if 1 or more are checked, don't show it. Anyway, this worked: if (!isset($_POST['maandag']) && !$_POST['maandag'] && !isset($_POST['dinsdag']) && !$_POST['dinsdag'] && !isset($_POST['geenvoork']) && !$_POST['geenvoork'])

Comment: @yi_H it may be ugly, but it works ;) i'll try to optimize another day.. main thing for now is that it works :D

Answer (score 3):

You can try doing a `print_r($_POST)` and see what the values of the fields are. That might help you determine what is going on with your submission/field values.

Answer (score 1):

i thing ur coding make complicate.,,

try like

```
<input type="checkbox" name="test[]"  value="1"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="test[]" value="2"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="test[]" value="3"/>
```

submit the value and get the result

Answer (score 0):

Set the proper value for you checkbox in HTML.

```
<input type="checkbox" ... value="1">
```

Your current accepted solution just complicates the PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

I just made a check upon a checkbox I am using and here are the values:

```
<input id="Isolated1" type="checkbox" value="1" name="Isolated1"></input>
```

In case when input is checked the following evaluates as:

```
isset( $_POST["Isolated1"] )

//True

( $_POST["Isolated1"] )

//True
```

In case when input is NOT checked:

```
isset( $_POST["Isolated1"] )

//False

( $_POST["Isolated1"] ) 

//Notice: Undefined index
```

Therefore, I suggest using [empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) function, simultaneously checking whether variable does not exist or its value equaling FALSE.

Comment: I think it is still relevant as the solution and fucntion itself is not outdated. Besides someone could find it useful not having to repeat the same test all over again. I almost always use google to find the solutions and then look through the first few answers...

Answer (score -1):

As prisonor said you need to check if it is empty(), although if it's not set at all this could give you a notice.

Your if would require:

```
isset($_POST['checkbox']) && !empty($_POST['checkbox'])
```

Edit: Stupid me, your right it doesnt return anything. Checking your post with print_r as posted below sounds like the best option.

Comment: empty() is not reliable. if the checkbox's value on the browser side is '0', empty() will be true. Any value in PHP which can be cast to an empty string counts as `empty()`.

Answer (score -1):

Actually that should work...

You could always set your checkbox to a value and specifically check that that value is returned:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="maandag"  value="1"/>

<?php if(isset($_POST['maandag']) && $_POST['maandag'] != '1') { /* ... */ }
```